# How to write the List data in Excel

Tags: java

List having data in this format
[{Row ID=7565.0, Product ID=test11223, Postal Code=98103.0}, {Row ID=7567.0, Product ID=test11213, Postal Code=98101.0}] Having more than 100 row ID record like this, I want to store that data in Excel in below format

Row Id     Order ID    Postal Code
7565       test11233    98103
7567       test11233    98101

Please help to share the code to write a above list data in excel. thnx

Comment: Show the code is impossible. You do not provide any kind of useful code to continue it.

Comment: ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery(contents);
ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
int columns = md.getColumnCount();
java.util.List<java.util.Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<java.util.Map<String, String>>();
ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
while (rs.next()) { 
  java.util.Map map = new HashMap();
    for (int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        String key = meta.getColumnName(i); 
               String value = rs.getString(key); 
              map.put(key, value); 
    }
    list.add(map);
}

Collections.shuffle(list);

Comment: I have to save the list data in Excel file.

Comment: Here we answer your question, not do your job!

Answer (score -1):

With [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org) you can write any kind of MS Office files.
Here is a [quick example](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) how write cells with it.

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
//Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");

// Create a row and put some cells in it. Rows are 0 based.
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
// Create a cell and put a value in it.
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(1);

// Or do it on one line.
row.createCell(1).setCellValue(1.2);
row.createCell(2).setCellValue(
     createHelper.createRichTextString("This is a string"));
row.createCell(3).setCellValue(true);

// Write the output to a file
try (OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls")) {
    wb.write(fileOut);
}
```